# django 1.8 allauth issue with custom form

Tags: forms, django-allauth, django-1.8

I'm using django allauth for my authentication and am having an issue with my custom form. I am using django 1.8 for the first time and things are a little different than in the past.

Here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FDUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here's my form:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import FDUserProfile

class FDSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FDUserProfile
        fields = ['organization']

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam')
    organization = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Company')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        profile = FDUserProfile(user=user, organization=self.cleaned_data['organization'])
        profile.save()
```

The error I get is the following:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: fdauth_fduserprofile.user_id
```

Now I don't want my user_id to be null and don't really understand why this is happening. I was able to simplify this form and use the User model as my form's model and just save the first_name and last_name fields however I need to store the company of the client as well. One other thing to note, and this is just another thing I've noticed. When I had this working with just the first_name and last_name, the user object would save but no email would send. I can cross that bridge once I get past this one.

TIA!